# JQuery color picker shows on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

So I am using jquery minicolors and have it set the way I need, but one issue. When the page loads, the color picker is already shown. It should only be shown when the input box is selected. Settings isn't changing anything nor is changing anything in the JS. What am I doing wrong here? I am attaching code below:

My html:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label data-toggle="tooltip" for="borderColor" title=
  "Enter a Color for the Border (Hexidecimal)"><span class=
  "glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tip"></span>&nbsp;Border Color</label>

  <div class=
  "minicolors minicolors-theme-bootstrap minicolors-position-bottom minicolors-position-right">
  <div class=
  "minicolors minicolors-theme-bootstrap minicolors-position-bottom minicolors-position-right minicolors-focus">
    <input class="form-control demo minicolors-input" id="text-field" size="7"
      type="text"> <span class=
      "minicolors-swatch minicolors-sprite"><span class=
      "minicolors-swatch-color" style=
      "background-color: rgb(86, 163, 52);"></span></span>

      <div class="minicolors-panel minicolors-slider-hue" style=
      "display: block; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="minicolors-slider minicolors-sprite">
          <div class="minicolors-picker" style="top: 107.916666666667px;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="minicolors-opacity-slider minicolors-sprite">
          <div class="minicolors-picker"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="minicolors-grid minicolors-sprite" style=
        "background-color: rgb(77, 255, 0);">
          <div class="minicolors-grid-inner"></div>

          <div class="minicolors-picker" style="top: 62px; right: 57px;">
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><span class="minicolors-swatch minicolors-sprite"><span class=
    "minicolors-swatch-color" style=
    "background-color: rgb(112, 194, 74);"></span></span>

    <div class="minicolors-panel minicolors-slider-hue" style=
    "display: none; opacity: .5;">
      <div class="minicolors-slider minicolors-sprite">
        <div class="minicolors-picker" style="top: 107.916666666667px;"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="minicolors-opacity-slider minicolors-sprite">
        <div class="minicolors-picker"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="minicolors-grid minicolors-sprite" style=
      "background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);">
        <div class="minicolors-grid-inner"></div>

        <div class="minicolors-picker" style="top: 35px; right: 93px;">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $.minicolors.defaults = $.extend($.minicolors.defaults, {
        animationSpeed: 50,
        animationEasing: 'swing',
        // change: null,
        changeDelay: 0,
        control: 'hue',
        defaultValue: '',
        hide: false,
        hideSpeed: 100,
        showSpeed: 100,
        inline: false,
        letterCase: 'uppercase',
        opacity: false,
        position: 'bottom right',
        show: true,
        action: 'click',
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        change: function(hex, opacity) {
          if (!hex) return;
          if (opacity) hex += ', ' + opacity;
          if (typeof console === 'object') {
            console.log(hex);
          }
        },
      });
      $('.minicolors input').minicolors({
        show: function() {
          console.log('Show event triggered!');
        }
      });
      $('.minicolors input').minicolors();
```

Comment: try using **$('.colorpicker').hide()** to hide the color picker..

Comment: try changing `hide: false,` to `hide: true,`

Comment: Have tried that as I thought that was the logical thing, but does not change how it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your HTML by default (display:none) and make it visible (.show) when the event happens.

Comment: The hide function is built in and thought I was using it right. The plugin is here with documentation: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/ . If I display: none, it won't show when right. Where were you suggesting that? Thanks much.